# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Our App should be able to go from the main storyboard to another storyboard which contains a splitViewController that leads to a searchbar.
We created the searchbar in another storyboard and connected it to the navigation controller like this:

```
@IBAction func artikelButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MasterViewController")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

If you then press that button the app crashes with the SIGABRT error.
The other 2 Buttons work fine, the difference is that they are .xib files.
Here's how we made the .xib buttons:

```
@IBAction func infoButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = InfoViewController(
        nibName: "InfoViewController",bundle: nil)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: make sure that `self.storyboard!` is not nil

Comment: Well I'm a noob, how do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you load your viewcontroller from XIB. then `self.storyboard` will always nil.

if you are using multiple storyboard or multiple XIB's A better solution 
have abstract method practice in your every viewcontroller to access from storyboard

Just like add following (change viewcontroller name and identifier as per yours )

```
// MARK: - Abstract Methods


public class func viewController () -> LoginVC {
    return StoryBoard.main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryBoard.controller.LoginVC) as! LoginVC
}



// Now access it with  LoginVC.viewController() and do push or present whatever your operation you requred
```

I manage everything in constant file

```
public struct StoryBoard {

static let main = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

       struct controller {
           static let LoginVC   =   "LoginView"

         }

}
```